# How can I let Azure PowerShell to remember the command line history?

Tags: powershell, azure

Azure PowerShell remembers command line history (as almost usable shell do since a few decades), but unfortunately it quickly suffers total amnesia after exiting and restarting. So it can not remembers it between sessions.

Is there any way to let **Azure PowerShell** to remember the command line history in the next session?

Answer (score 2):

My current method based on [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/01/perserving-command-history-across-sessions.aspx):

Step 1: Make a PowerShell profile, [see Example 3 here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx). If it already exists, skip to step 2.

Step 2: Add this to your profile.

```
$MaximumHistoryCount = 1KB
if (!(Test-Path "$((Get-ChildItem $PROFILE).DirectoryName)\history.csv"))
{   New-Item "$((Get-ChildItem $PROFILE).DirectoryName)\history.csv" -ItemType File -Force
}

function bye
{   Get-History -Count $MaximumHistoryCount | Export-CSV -Path "$((Get-ChildItem $PROFILE).DirectoryName)\history.csv"
    exit
}

if (Test-path "$((Get-ChildItem $PROFILE).DirectoryName)\history.csv")
{   Import-CSV "$((Get-ChildItem $PROFILE).DirectoryName)\history.csv" | Add-History
}
register-engineevent PowerShell.Exiting -action { bye }
```

Notes:

- You may need to use a different path, such as the original article's location.
- Use `Get-History` and `Invoke-History` for running previous commands.
- You can also use `#[tab]`, example: type #5 then press tab to expand the original command.
- Some users reported that the history is only saved if they quit PowerShell by typing `exit` instead of closing the window.
- This is for the PowerShell history, not the console buffer. Pressing up/down only works for the commands you entered on the current console.

Additional resources and some alternative methods:

- [Understanding the Six PowerShell Profiles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx)
- [Use PowerShell History to Speed Repetitive Commands](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/18/use-powershell-history-to-speed-repetitive-commands.aspx)
- [Saving PowerShell commands across sessions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26261/Saving-PowerShell-commands-across-sessions)
- [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine), A bash inspired readline implementation for PowerShell
- [The Search for a Better PowerShell Console Experience](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/16/the-search-for-a-better-powershell-console-experience.aspx)
- [PSReadLine: A Better Line Editing Experience for the PowerShell Console](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/psreadline-a-better-line-editing-experience-for-the-powershell-console/)

PSReadLine offers "Automatic saving of history, including sharing history across live sessions." PSReadLine also does a whole lot more than just history preservation. Also, if you want up and down to be even more useful in the history, that last one lists additional key bindings that make it even more useful.

Comment: This is a fantastically informative answer! it makes me slightly ashamed of the bits of waffle I've generally replied with ;)